# jstl - unable to load class for jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

When I try to add jstl tags into my jsp I get this:
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP

JSP may look like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<body>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="post" >
        <tr>
            <td>${post.author}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to write

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

- the result is the same.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Do you have jstl dependency in your lib? What's your server?

Comment: what is `${list}` supposed to be?

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception. And read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the problem was in the wrong version of jstl (in dependencies in pom.xml).